# Javascript get integer value of url parameter to replace it in function

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some difficulties with javascript. I'm currently working out a pagination skipper.

```
    function skip(s)
    {
    var url = window.location.toString();
    if(location.href.match(/(\?|&)currentpage=x($|&|=)/))
    {
        url=url.replace('currentpage=x','currentpage='+s);
        window.location=url;    
    }
    else
    {
        var newUrl = url+"&currentpage="+s;
        window.location=newUrl;
    }
}
```

I would like x to match any integer, so the entire string will be replaced.

Thanks!

Comment: `\d+` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you're looking is this:

```
/((\?|&)currentpage=)\d+/
```

It matches *and captures* `?|&currentpage=`, and matches the number that follows, but does not capture them. You can then replace the entire match with a string of your choice:

```
var newUrl = location.href.replace(/([?&]currentpage=)\d+/, '$1'+s);
```

Assuming that `s` here is the value for `currentpage` you want to replace the *x* in your example with. I've replaced the `(\?|&)` with a character class: `[?&]`. It simply matches a single character that is either a ? or an &. In the replacement string I back-reference the matched group ([?&]currentpage=), using `$1`, and concatenate `s` to it. It's as simple as that. To redirect:

```
location.href = location.href.replace(
    /([?&]currentpage=)\d+/,
   '$1' + s
);
```

And you're home free. Try it out in your console, like so:

```
'http://www.example.com/page?param1=value1&currentpage=123&param2=foobar'.replace(
    /([?&]currentpage=)\d+/,
   '$1124'//replaced + s with 124
);
//output:
//"http://www.example.com/page?param1=value1&currentpage=124&param2=foobar"
```

Comment: Wasn't familiar with regex. But thank you! Now understood regex a bit

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code,

```
function addParameter(url, param, value) {
    // Using a positive lookahead (?=\=) to find the
    // given parameter, preceded by a ? or &, and followed
    // by a = with a value after than (using a non-greedy selector)
    // and then followed by a & or the end of the string
    var val = new RegExp('(\\?|\\&)' + param + '=.*?(?=(&|$))', 'i'),
        qstring = /\?.+$/;

    // Check if the parameter exists
    if (val.test(url)) {
        // if it does, replace it, using the captured group
        // to determine & or ? at the beginning
        return url.replace(val, '$1' + param + '=' + value);
    }
    else if (qstring.test(url)) {
        // otherwise, if there is a query string at all
        // add the param to the end of it
        return url + '&' + param + '=' + value;
    }
    else {
        // if there's no query string, add one
        return url + '?' + param + '=' + value;
    }
}
```

Usage,

```
function skip(s) {
    window.location = addParameter(location.href, "currentpage", s);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0vb5wjag/)